# Airspace Issue : DevExpress WPF DialogBox popped up over a WPF backgroud that uses WinFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm hit by a terrible AirSpace problem (again!). Basically, on a button click, I'm displaying a DialogBox control over a WPF layout that has used WindowsFormsHost in it, and the DialogBox wouldn't always display properly! Sometimes,(when the diaplay is scewring up that is) I'm seeing the content of the DialogBox fine, but the OK-Cancel buttons and Title Bars are vanishing away!

Following is how I create & show the DialogBox in the button's click event handler:

```
DXDialog dDialog = new DXDialog(culture.ShowingMenu_Customization, DialogButtons.OkCancel, true);
var result = dDialog.ShowDialog();
```

P.S : I read on another thread that the following LOC fix these issues, but where exactly should I plug these LOC ? I added them at the end of my earlier mentioned click eventhandler, but there was no difference in result.

```
DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(object parameter) {
        frame.Continue = false;
        return null;
    }), null);
Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
```

Regards,
Ron.

Comment: After you load the window/dialog. Try to resize the dialog by adding some values to Height and Width like Dialog.Height = Dialog.ActualHeight+2; It will kind of solve the issue.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian if I add a line like  "dDialog.Height = dDialog.ActualHeight + 2;" after "var result = dDialog.ShowDialog();", the execution actually never reaches the 2nd line until the Dialog window is closed. So, it doesn't quite seem to work that way.

Comment: Add the line in the dDialog.loaded event.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian - I already did something similar, and it does solve the problem partially. Adding the lines in dDialog.Loaded or dDialog.Activate doesn't solve the problem, but doing it in dDialog.ContentRendered does! However, I get the slight flickering/twinkling effect on screen - as the rendering first gets lost due to airspace problem & then gets re-rendered on the height adjustment. Any idea how i could refine the solution and get rid of this flickering ?